# find a single quote at the end of a line starting with "mySqlQueryToArray"

Tags: regex, perl, sublimetext3

I'm trying to use regex to find single quotes (so I can turn them all into double quotes) anywhere in a line that starts with mySqlQueryToArray (a function that makes a query to a SQL DB). I'm doing the regex in Sublime Text 3 which I'm pretty sure uses Perl Regex. I would like to have my regex match with every single quote in a line so for example I might have the line:

```
mySqlQueryToArray($con, "SELECT * FROM Template WHERE Name='$name'");
```

I want the regex to match in that line both of the quotes around `$name` but no other characters in that line. I've been trying to use `(?<=mySqlQueryToArray.*)'` but it tells me that the look behind assertion is invalid. I also tried `(?<=mySqlQueryToArray)(?<=.*)'` but that's also invalid. Can someone guide me to a regex that will accomplish what I need?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25331428/3933728 is actually a much cleaner answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25331428/3933728 is a better answer.

I'm not good enough with RegEx nor ST to do this in one step. But I can do it in two:

1/ Search for all `mySqlQueryToArray` strings
Open the search panel: <kbd>⌘F</kbd> or `Find->Find...`
Make sure you have the Regex (`.*` ) button selected (bottom left) and the wrap selector (all other should be off)
Search for: `^\s*mySqlQueryToArray.*$`

- `^` beginning of line
- `\s*` any indentation
- `mySqlQueryToArray` your call
- `.*` whatever is behind
- `$` end of line

Click on `Find All`
This will select every occurrence of what you want to modify.

2/ Enter the replace mode
<kbd>⌥⌘F</kbd> or `Find->Replace...`
This time, make sure that wrap, Regex AND In selection are active [image].
Them search for `'([^']*)'` and replace with `"\1"`.

- `'` are your single quotes
- `(...)` si the capturing block, referenced by `\1` in the replace field
- `[^']*` is for any character that is not a single quote, repeated

Then hit `Replace All`

I know this is a little more complex that the other answer, but this one tackles cases where your line would contain several single-quoted string. Like this:

```
mySqlQueryToArray($con, "SELECT * FROM Template WHERE Name='$name' and Value='1234'");
```

If this is too much, I guess something like find: `(?<=mySqlQueryToArray)(.*?)'([^']*)'(.*?)` and replace it with `\1"\2"\3` will be enough.

Comment: Arguably pet peeves: why do you match the rest of the line (both with `.*$` and with the `\3` group) if you're not using them? Also remember to be careful with `[^']*`, as contrarily to `.*` is will match newlines as well. Thanks for the link btw, I appreciate the length of your post :)

Comment: I added this in a hurry, and I was sure this one was working. That's why the `\3` is a bit overkill.
And thx for the `[^']` precision, but ST doesn't match newlines in this pattern, that's why.

Answer (score 2):

To find any number of single quotes in a line starting with your keyword you can use the `\G` anchor ("end of last match") by replacing:

```
(^\h*mySqlQueryToArray|(?!^)\G)([^\n\r']*)'
```

With `\1\2<replacement>`: see [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/nW7wX4/2).

**Explanation**

```
( ^\h*mySqlQueryToArray  # beginning of line: check the keyword is here
 | (?!^)\G )             # if not at the BOL, check we did match sth on this line
( [^\n\r']* ) '          # capture everything until the next single quote
```

The general idea is to match everything until the next single quote with `([^\n\r']*)'` in order to replace it with `\2<replacement>`, *but* do so only if this everything is:

- right after the beginning keyword (`^mySqlQueryToArray`), or
- after the end of the last match (`(?!^)\G`): in that case we know we have the keyword and are on a relevant line.

`\h*` accounts for any started indent, as suggested by Xælias (`\h` being shortcut for any kind of horizontal whitespace).

Comment: Nice, this works perfectly.
I'ld just use `(^\s*mySql...` for when the line is indented.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this:

```
(mySqlQueryToArray.*?)'(.*?)'(.*)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/iV2wE6/1)**

Check the substitution section.

Comment: I want to just match the `'` in the line, this grabs the entire line

Comment: You then have 3 groups, you can reference, \1 is everything before the first `'`, \2 is the quoted text, and \3 everything that comes after.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\K`, see this regex:

```
mySqlQueryToArray[^']*\K'(.*?)'
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/zZ7gS3/1).

Comment: Clearly it works in your demo but it doesn't retrieve any results when I try to use it. I'm not sure what's happening there.